# Intuition behind the KKT conditions

Tags: machine-learning, svm

what is the physical significance of KKT conditions in the lagrangian dual problem formulation while solving for the SVM optimization primal problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Mathematically, the KKT conditions are equations that must be met in order to prove strong duality, which means that the solution to the dual problem will be equivalent to the solution of the primal problem.

In concept, when you run the code for SVM, the KKT conditions are going to be the primary reason why all the non-border alphas end up going to 0 and, consequently, the support vectors will be the only alphas > 0.